# Calculating $\int^{2\pi}_0 |\sin x-\cos x| dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

The result of :
$\int^{2pi}_0 |\sin x-\cos x|dx$ is:

a:$4 \sqrt{2}$

b:$0$

c:$2\sqrt{2}$

d:$\pi$

e:$2\sqrt{2}+1$

I tried to solve the problem and loosen the integral such that : $\int^{\pi/4}_0 -\sin x+\cos xdx$+$\int^{\pi/2}_{pi/4} (\sin x-\cos x)dx$+$\int^{\pi}_{\pi/2} (\sin x-\cos x)dx$ +$\int^{5\pi/4}_{\pi} (\sin x-\cos x)dx$$\int^{3\pi/2}_{5\pi/4} (-\sin x+\cos x)dx$+$\int^{2\pi}_{3\pi/2} (-\sin x+\cos x)dx$ and get to the result c but my teacger told me that it is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really have to split into so many regions as from your working, only $3$ regions sufficies, that is from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}4$, from $\frac{\pi}4$ to $\frac{5\pi}4$ and $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ to $2\pi$.

By symmetric, the required region is

\begin{align}2\int_{\frac{\pi}4}^{\frac{5\pi}4} (\sin x - \cos x) \, dx &= 2\sqrt2 \int_{\frac{\pi}4}^{\frac{5\pi}4} \sin \left( x-\frac{\pi}4\right)  \, dx\\&=2\sqrt2 \int_0^\pi \sin x \, dx 
\end{align}

Can you complete this?